# Replace '0' with 1 in phone numbers Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to replace users phone numbers to start with 1 instead of 0 but I'm stuck.

I have this line
`$mobileNumber = implode(',', $postData['phone']);`

which outputs `"0445329500,0569075729,0456786942"` I want to replace all the first 0 with 1 so instead of `0445329500,0569075729,0456786942` it should be `1445329500`,`1569075729`,`1456786942`

I have tried this `Str::replaceFirst('0','1',$mobileNumber);` it only replaces the first number `1445329500`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rather than implode, I suggest you loop through the array and update the numbers there.

```php
foreach ($postData['phone'] as $index => $value) {
    $postData['phone'][$index] = Str::replaceFirst('0','1',$value);
}
//then you can implode
$mobileNumber = implode(',', $postData['phone']);
```

Comment: If it was the answer can you flag it as a validated one ? ;)